# World point to Isometric point - Need help understanding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, isometric

Now I know this question has been asked and answered several hundred times on this website and many others, but I cannot find an explanation on why the calculations work, and how I can actually change it to my needs.

This is my current function:

```
//Converts X, Y from the 2D World to a Point in the Isometric Grid
public static Vector2 WorldToIsometric(float x, float y, int scale)
{
    Vector2 point = new Vector2(x, y);
    Vector2 iso_point = new Vector2(point.x, point.y);
    float half_scale = scale / 2;

    iso_point.x = point.x - (point.y * 2) + half_scale;
    iso_point.y = point.x + (point.y * 2) - half_scale;

    iso_point.x /= scale;
    iso_point.y /= scale;

    iso_point.x = Mathf.Floor (iso_point.x);
    iso_point.y = Mathf.Floor (iso_point.y);

    return iso_point;
}
```

Key:

```
        x  =  mouse x in world
        y  =  mouse y in world
    scale  =  width of isometric tile
    point  =  mouse point in world
iso_point  =  mouse point on isometric grid
```

What I want the output to look like:

[image]

What the output actually looks like:

[image]

I just can't wrap my head around the concepts of changing the code, I've probably been at this took long and had too much coffee, but whatever I change it just doesn't seem to work out like I thought it would.

Feel free to link a detailed tutorial on how it works mathematically, but I cannot find anything that actually helps me understand how to alter the code.

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd have to put the whole formula together,

```
iso_point.x = point.x/scale - (point.y + 1) / (scale / 2);
```

In your case, point.x/scale is what increases X as you move your mouse to the right. If you move your mouse up, you can see that iso_point.x will decrease by point.y / (scale/2).

scale/2 comes from the fact that the tile's height = width/2

As you want iso_point.x to increase as both point.x and point.y increase, you'll want something like

```
iso_point.x = point.x + (point.y * 2) - half_scale;
```

In the same way, iso_point.y will have to increase as point.x decreases and point.y increases:

```
iso_point.y = -point.x + (point.y * 2) - half_scale;
```

Comment: I'm gonna give this a test, it's very late and I've been working on this so long, but that simple explanation makes total sense... been reading complex mathematical explanations so far

Comment: perfect, I finally understand in my brain how it all works